# Using ASP.NET MVC 5 and Jasig's CAS Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication, cas, owin, jasig

I understand that CAS uses Forms Authentication and MVC 5 has now moved to OWIN. I've done some research and have found that there are a few people trying to implement this- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jasig-cas-dev/vPqa5X6aYew/FwciRjilbgEJ, and I have downloaded and included the files from Will Dean's Git repository- https://github.com/willdean/owin-cas.

My question is, how do I configure this to work with my CAS server? I have changed some login url variables but have had no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've a custom CAS implementation in our organization and Will Dean's project worked for me ...

Take a look at `Startup.Auth.cs` and configure properly `casOptions.CasServerUrlBase`.

ex: `casOptions.CasServerUrlBase = "https://cas.contoso.com";`

And don't put trailing / at url end :)

Maybe you need to implement your own CasAuthenticationProvider in order to customize it for your CAS environment, but I would first try to debug the authentication process to rule out things like wrong magic strings ... and use Fiddler to intercept request and responses!